# DC/OS vs just plain Mesos+Marathon

Tags: cluster-computing, mesos, marathon, mesosphere, dcos

we are looking to build a cluster of Compute Nodes for Deep Learning model training jobs, some of them on the cloud and others locally, that have NVIDIA GPUs in them. We felt that using Mesos and the framework Marathon (M&M) would be our best options to schedule the cluster. However the documentations for (M&M) seem to be very ambiguous (or at least to me, sorry I'm an intern) and I'm running into a lot of issues concerning Zookeeper and the connections between the nodes.

Plus, it seems like Mesosphere are giving much more importance to DC/OS when it comes to tutorials and docs, and I guess it will also be patched more regularly and its interfaces (GUI and CLI) look much more user-friendly.

So I was wondering if by dropping the exploration of (M&M) and moving to  DC/OS, would we lose a lot of control over the cluster? In M&M do we have perks that cannot be given in the Open Source Edition of DC/OS? like monitoring the machines, logging results etc.. If I ask my manager we might also get the Enterprise edition so that's not really a problem, but does DC/OS apply an abstraction layer that isn't really preferable to advanced users?

Answer (score 2):

DC/OS is build around Apache Mesos and Marathon and gives a good default setup for zookeeper, networking, .... So IMO it is a good place to start as you can still use all M&M and Mesos features + the DC/OS features and ease of setup.

Disclaimer: I am working for Mesosphere.